# How to use JsonNames to parse multiple names for JSON field in Kotlinx Serialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, json-deserialization, jsonparser, kotlinx.serialization

How to use JsonNames to parse multiple names for JSON field in Kotlinx Serialization. For normal data class it works fine

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable
data class Project(@JsonNames("title") val name: String)

fun main() {
  val project = Json.decodeFromString<Project>("""{"name":"kotlinx.serialization"}""")
  println(project)
  val oldProject = Json.decodeFromString<Project>("""{"title":"kotlinx.coroutines"}""")
  println(oldProject)
}

Project(name=kotlinx.serialization)
Project(name=kotlinx.coroutines)
```

But for Type generic data class like GoogleBaseApiResponse where T is of any data class

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable
data class GoogleBaseApiResponse<T> (
    var status : String = "",
    var error_message : String? = null,
    @JsonNames("results", "predictions", "result") var responseData : T? = null
)

Where T is Something like data class or arraylist of data class
```

Following Errors occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Problem with constructing exception message
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializerClassLowering.lower(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:184)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.acceptChildren(IrClass.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrVisitorsKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrVisitors.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitClass(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.acceptChildren(IrFile.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrVisitorsKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrVisitors.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitElement(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitPackageFragment(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:190)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitPackageFragment(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFile(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:200)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitFile(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFile(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:198)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitFile(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt$runOnFileInOrder$1.visitFile(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.accept(IrFile.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrVisitorsKt.acceptVoid(IrVisitors.kt:11)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtensionKt.runOnFileInOrder(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationLoweringExtension.generate(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$lambda$1(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:186)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:218)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.convertToIr(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:179)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
```

Whether is possible to use @JsonNames annotations in Type generic data class?.

Sample Code is below

```
val httpResponse = httpClient.post {
                    url(PLACES_DETAILS)
                    formData {
                        parameter(PLACE_ID_KEY, userAppLocation.userCityId)
                        parameter(API_KEY, appSettings.getAppConfigModel()?.getMapApiKey())
                    }
                }.call.response
                httpResponse.body<GoogleBaseApiResponse<AddressFromLatLngModel>>().also { apiResponse ->
                    if (apiResponse.status.lowercase() == Constants.OKAY_STATUS.lowercase()) {
                        Napier.d(tag = tag, message = apiResponse.printJSONValue())
                        val newUserAppLocation = userAppLocation.copy(
                            userLat = apiResponse. responseData?.geometry?.location?.lat?:0.0,
                            userLng = apiResponse. responseData?.geometry?.location?.lng?:0.0
                        )
                        emit(NetworkResult.Success(newUserAppLocation))
                    } else {
                        emit(NetworkResult.Error(apiResponse.error_message))
                    }
                }



Where,
GoogleBaseApiResponse --> 
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable
data class GoogleBaseApiResponse<T> (
    var status : String = "",
    var error_message : String? = null,
    @JsonNames("results", "predictions", "result") var responseData : T? = null
)


AddressFromLatLngModel -->
@Serializable
data class AddressFromLatLngModel(
    var formatted_address : String = "",
    var geometry : GeometryModel = GeometryModel(),
    var address_components : ArrayList<AddressComponentsModel> = arrayListOf()
)

GeometryModel is --> 
@Serializable
data class GeometryModel(
    var location : LocationModel = LocationModel()
)

LocationModel is -->
@Serializable
data class LocationModel(
    var lat : Double = 0.0,
    var lng : Double = 0.0
)

AddressComponentsModel -->
@Serializable
data class AddressComponentsModel(
    var long_name : String = "",
    var short_name : String = ""
)
```

Comment: When are you getting that error? Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: @Jorn, Any answer regarding my updated question.

Comment: The classes you added have neither `JsonNames` nor any generic types on the class (only on the fields), nor any new info on the extension. In other words, you haven't added anything I can use to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works just fine for me:

```
    val json = Json.encodeToString(GoogleBaseApiResponse("st", "err", 42))
        .replace("responseData", "predictions") // simulate "alternate" name
    println(json) // {"status":"st","error_message":"err","predictions":42}
    val x = Json.decodeFromString<GoogleBaseApiResponse<Int>>(json)
    println(x) // GoogleBaseApiResponse(status=st, error_message=err, responseData=42)
```

But since your error happens in the `SerializationLoweringExtension`, I'd look into configuration regarding that extension, and code that makes use of it. If you post more relevant details, we might be able to help you further.

Comment: I am using @JsonNames("results", "predictions", "result") annotation in GoogleBaseApiResponse. Without @JsonNames everything works. My scenario is to use **@JsonNames** because key **results** is for fetching address list from google, **predictions** is for fetching address by search query and **result** is for getting address data based on Latitude and Longitude

Comment: @SumanRadhakrishnan Still works with the alternate name, see updated answer. Like I said, your problem is not related to `@JsonNames` or the generic parameter.

Comment: Then why SerializationLoweringExtension error happend to me?

Comment: There's a problem relating to that extension in code you haven't posted, so we can't know that.

Comment: But its works fine without @JsonNames. So I think their is no problem in extension

Comment: @SumanRadhakrishnan Then how do you explain that my example works fine?

Comment: In my case T is Not a Integer or String. Its Something like Data class or ArrayList of Data Class

Comment: @SumanRadhakrishnan That sounds like relevant information that should be in the question, along with the actual JSON you are parsing.

Comment: How do i post my sample code in comment section?

Comment: You don't. Edit your question instead.

Comment: I updated my questing. Please check whether it okay or not?

Answer (score -1):

if i got it you need to user same parameter to different json keys
you need to use alternate  attribute

so your data class will be like

```
@Serializable
```

data class Project(@SerializedName("title",alternate =["name"]) val name: String)